# golang struct from other package

Tags: go, struct

**Situation:**

I've the following project structure:

```
root
    parser
       parser.go
    builtin
        exit.go
        hi.go
    structs
        base_structs.go
    main.go
```

.. and the `base_structs.go` file looks like this:

```
package structs

type Built_in_func func([] string)

type Built_in struct {
    s string
    f Built_in_func
}
```

I've imported the package in my `main.go` and I'm referencing the struct with `structs.Built_in`.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
var builtin_list [] structs.Built_in

builtin_list = append(builtin_list, structs.Built_in{s:"exit", f:builtin.Exit})
builtin_list = append(builtin_list, structs.Built_in{s:"hi", f:builtin.Hi})
```

But I'm getting this error:

> unknown structs.Built_in field 's' in struct literal

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) and the ["Basics" section in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3)

Answer (score 14):

In Go, the visibility of a name outside a package is determined by whether its first character is upper case.

So the field `s` is actually not visible from outside the package `structs` and you get that error.

If you define your struct like (note the upper case):

```
type Built_in struct {
    S string
    F Built_in_func
}
```

Then this will work (again the upper case):

```
structs.Built_in{S:"exit", F:builtin.Exit}
```

You can read more here:

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names